# Iptables SNAT routing to openVZ containers

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, openvz

For this to make sense I need to set the scene a bit.

I have a dedicated server with 5 public Ips : A.B.C.1 to A.B.C.5

A.B.C.1 manages the dedicated server itself, and A.B.C.2 - 5 are used for OpenVZ containers.
I want each public IP to be linked to multiple containers - For instance A.B.C.2 should forward traffic on Port 80 to the container at 192.168.2.1 and traffic on port 21 to the container at 192.168.2.2 .

Using IPTables to NAT the traffic works if only one external IP is in use, however if I try to add multiple public IPs to route I lose all network connection to all containers, they cannot ping and cannot receive incoming traffic. However access to the Host node remains.

The output of iptables -t nat -L on the host node is below:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             A.B.C.2             udp dpt:9987 to:192.168.2.1:9987
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             A.B.C.2             tcp dpt:10011 to:192.168.2.2:10011
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             A.B.C.2             tcp dpt:30033 to:192.168.2.2:30033
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             A.B.C.3             tcp dpt:80 to:192.168.3.1:80
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             A.B.C.4             tcp dpt:25565 to:192.168.4.1:25565

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
SNAT       all  --  192.168.2.0/24        anywhere            to:A.B.C.2
SNAT       all  --  192.168.3.0/24        anywhere            to:A.B.C.3
SNAT       all  --  192.168.4.0/24        anywhere            to:A.B.C.4

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

The Host node has one phyical NIC - eth0, which has an IP of A.B.C.1

The Host is running Centos 6.3, and each of the VMs are running Debian 7.

My OpenVZ kernel version is  2.6.32-042stab108.2

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that all public IPs are set on the external interface of your physical host, with the correct netmask
2. Check that all the VMs have as default gateway the IP address of the bridge they're connected to (check that the bridges correct have IPs)
3. Check that ip_forwarding is enabled
4. Use SNAT to mask the VMs behind the correct public IPs
5. Use DNAT to forward incoming traffic to the correct VMs